# How to find what MPM model Apache is using in Linux (worker, prefork or event)

Tags: apache, apache2

Where I can get information about what kind of MPM Apache is using in my Linux system?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can see this by checking which modules are compiled with Apache.

See output of the following command:

```
# httpd -l
```

From there, seek for `prefork.c`.

Comment: I like @user131003's answer because it tells you in plain english: 
"Server MPM:     Prefork
   threaded:     no"

Answer (score 73):

```
httpd -V
```

then look for the `Server MPM` line.

Example:

```
# httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug  2 2013 08:02:15
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
```

Comment: Similarly to what was mentioned in the [comments beneath the currently accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225404/how-to-find-what-mpm-model-apache-is-using-in-linux-worker-prefor-or-event#comment31195765_8639774), on some systems (such as Ubuntu) you should use `apache2 -V`.

Comment: `apache2 -V` does not look anything like the output above (for me), however `apachectl -V` do.

Answer (score 47):

noticed the previous answers don't  mention  `apachectl`  !

[dlam@some-ubuntu-box~] $ `apachectl -V | grep -i mpm`

Server MPM:     event

--

[dlam@some-fedora-box:~] $ `httpd -V | grep -i mpm`

Server MPM:     Prefork

Comment: Another option is to list Compiled in modules using following command:    
`/usr/sbin/apache2 -l`
And in the output look for worker.c, prefork.c or event.c as one only of them will be present indicating the respective MPM module your apache2 is using.

Comment: @okwap as from @JorgeeFG answer this `a2query -M` works on Ubuntu

Comment: For me that was the only working method, because all others did not show any MPM. apach2 -V showed "Server MPM:" and nothing more. In my case "event" was enabled.

Answer (score 35):

In Ubuntu 14.04

```
a2query -M
```

Tells `event`, `prefork`, `worker`

You can change it by adding symbolic links for `mpm_<chosen>` from `mods-available` to `mods-enabled` in `/etc/apache2`.

Only one is allowed in a time.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: For some reason on my (AWS) Ubuntu 14.04, none of the required environment variables are defined, so none of the other solutions work. This one did.

Answer (score 1):

If it is linux,it should be prefork by default. Read [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mpm.html#defaults) for more information about apache mpm.